# How to create multiple wallet addresses for a single node?

Tags: wallet, cli-wallet, iota-cli

I'm tring to create a website where iota of multiple users can be stored in a wallet using php. Function needed are separate address for each user and they should be able to retrieve balance. I do have [iota cli](https://github.com/iotaledger/cli-app) running on my server. Mine is an amazon linux ec2 instance.

If anyone has suggestions of php wallets to use or some beginners guide it would be really helpful.

Comment: Please clarify. "iota-cli" already offer primitives of a wallet (in fact: it is wallet).

Comment: I needed the cli to be interacted from a website. How can I do that ?

Comment: This is a PHP question. Read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php and maybe ask on stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks anyway. I thought there will be some php libraries for that. Do you know of any ?